# Server 2008 Radius stopped working

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, radius, nps

i've had a working 2008 Server with NPS as a Radius Server running for authentication of wifi devices, VPN Connections and Logins from Cisco devices.

Suddenly the server stopped responding.
- No errors in the Windows logs
- NPS is listenning on the required ports
- Firewall settings are ok and the behavior stay's the same when disabling Firewall

I reinstalled NPS service windows say it's running but there are no entries in the windows logs.
The internal INxxx Log has no error messages.
i've imported the configuration of the secondary Radius server (which is working perfectly) but no change.

can anybody suggest where to look or what to change to get this work again?

thanks

Thomas

Comment: How did you resolve this problem?